# How to place content inside custompaint widget?

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: CustomPaint(
            painter: RPSCustomPainter(),
            child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.73.toDouble(),
                child: Text('Hi Nithya'))));
  }
}



class RPSCustomPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint0 = Paint()
      ..color = const Color.fromARGB(255, 33, 150, 243)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 1;

    Path path0 = Path();
    path0.moveTo(size.width * 0.3147368, size.height * 0.1385714);
    path0.lineTo(size.width * 0.3145895, size.height * 0.4253429);
    path0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.3334211, size.height * 0.4532571,
        size.width * 0.3331895, size.height * 0.4633429);
    path0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.3334526, size.height * 0.4708429,
        size.width * 0.3147368, size.height * 0.4957143);
    path0.lineTo(size.width * 0.3136842, size.height * 0.7828571);
    path0.lineTo(size.width * 0.7378947, size.height * 0.7842857);
    path0.lineTo(size.width * 0.7368421, size.height * 0.4985714);
    path0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.7134000, size.height * 0.4737143,
        size.width * 0.7131368, size.height * 0.4655000);
    path0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.7134000, size.height * 0.4558571,
        size.width * 0.7368421, size.height * 0.4271429);
    path0.lineTo(size.width * 0.7357895, size.height * 0.1428571);
    path0.lineTo(size.width * 0.3147368, size.height * 0.1385714);
    path0.close();

    canvas.drawPath(path0, paint0);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

[image]

I want the text to print inside the shape . But it is printing outside. How to increase or decrease the size of the shape based on content's width and height? I want the content to print only inside the custom shape. The shape should adjust to content's width and height automatically. How to achieve it?.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping your child Widget by Center Widget will solve the issue...

below code for your reference

```
CustomPaint(
          painter: RPSCustomPainter(),
          child: SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.73.toDouble(),
              child: const Center(child: Text('Hi Hari'))
          ),
     );
```

have a good day!!!